# PDF not displayed in object tag IE10

Tags: html, pdf

I have the tag

```
<object width="900" height="1200" type="application/pdf" 
        data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Qcm9kdWN...">    
</object>
```

which will not display in IE10 nor will getting the data to a url but works perfectly in Chrome and FF.

I have tried adding in `classid =clsid:ca8a9780-280d-11cf-a24d-444553540000` without any joy.